# Using a Normal Button (Non-Radio/Checkbox), how can I ensure only one value is chosen AND deselects another if one is chosen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is a very cut-down version to visualize what I'd like to do.](https://codepen.io/mlee99/pen/BaJVoNz)

My HTML

```
 <p class="call">Please select a number.</p>
  <div class="button-flex">
   <button class="rating">1</button>
   <button class="rating">2</button>
   <button class="rating">3</button>
   <button class="rating">4</button>
   <button class="rating">5</button>
  </div>
```

My JS

```
let allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");

allBtns.forEach((option) => {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    option.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  });
});
```

Essentially, I want a user to be able to click on only a single rating (1 thru 5) that will eventually be used to update a string.

The main problem I'd like to tackle right now is being able to select one value, pick another one, and have the previously chosen value be deselected. I was able to find a method using radios, and checkboxes will work,  but I also want to keep the button style because that's how it's supposed to be displayed.

Is this possible with a normal button element?

Comment: are you using something like react or vue?

Comment: @Mulan No, I just started using js like a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should memoize last button, then change it back on next click, like this:

```js
let allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");
let lastBtn;

allBtns.forEach((option) => {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    lastBtn && (lastBtn.style.backgroundColor = null);
    (lastBtn = option).style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="call">Please select a number.</p>
  <div class="button-flex">
   <button class="rating">1</button>
   <button class="rating">2</button>
   <button class="rating">3</button>
   <button class="rating">4</button>
   <button class="rating">5</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: How does this code work exactly? I don't quite understand the semantics, but this is the answer that solves my problem.

Comment: @Marcus Can you specify what part you did not understood, to help me be more succinct with an answer?

Comment: I apologize. More specifically, how does the "lastBtn && (lastBtn.style..)" and "(lastBtn = option). work exactly? Are these conditional statements?

Comment: That first statement is a ["short-circuited"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) conjunction operator, the second is just an assignment operation, both are using [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping).

Answer (score 3):

```js
let allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");

allBtns.forEach((option) => {
  option.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    allBtns.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('active');
    });
    
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.rating.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="call">Please select a number.</p>
<div class="button-flex">
 <button role="radio" class="rating">1</button>
 <button role="radio" class="rating">2</button>
 <button role="radio" class="rating">3</button>
 <button role="radio" class="rating">4</button>
 <button role="radio" class="rating">5</button>
</div>
```

Identifies the currently selected button element with .active

When the button is selected, remove the .active from all Button Elements and insert the .active into the newly selected button.

Comment: With this answer, would I be able to check if it has the "active" class to store the value and then update a string?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Do you want to get the value of a button with class "active"?

Comment: Due to my JS inexperience, I neglected that every time the button is clicked on, the innerText value is captured automatically due to how I declared/initialized the variable. Please ignore my last question.